# Cannot inherits from new Buffer implementation

Tags: node.js, inheritance, buffer

Node v4.0.0 comes with a refreshed Buffer class based on Javascript built-in Uint8Array.

Here is how the inheritance is made, as far as I know:

```
Buffer.prototype.__proto__ = Uint8Array.prototype;
Buffer.__proto__ = Uint8Array;
```

([full diff here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/63da0dfd3a4460e117240e84b57af2137469497e#diff-c28ab5e2f9b7f2f9890ac44e7370af59R40))

First question: Why do *Buffer.__proto__* is set to Uint8Array constructor function? I never saw that before and I don't really get it.

Then, I'm trying to upgrade the [node-ogg](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-ogg) module, and there is one class inheriting from the Buffer class:

```
function ogg_packet (buffer) {
  if (!Buffer.isBuffer(buffer)) {
    buffer = new Buffer(binding.sizeof_ogg_packet);
  }

  buffer.__proto__ = ogg_packet.prototype;
  return buffer;
}
inherits(ogg_packet, Buffer);
```

([source](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-ogg/blob/master/lib/packet.js#L22))

When I execute the tests, it fails silently.
When I try to print the newly created ogg_packet during tests execution, I get that error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: argument should be a Buffer
```

Here is my debug code:

```
packet = new ogg_packet();
console.log('PACKET', packet);
```

Also, [here is the upgrade branch to nan v2 (and node v4)](https://github.com/corentingurtner/node-ogg/tree/upgrade-nan)

So my second question: How can I make it works with the new Buffer implementation?

Thanks

**Update**:
I tried to change the way the constructor function of ogg_packet is working:

```
function ogg_packet (buffer) {
  if (!Buffer.isBuffer(buffer)) {
    Buffer.call(this, binding.sizeof_ogg_packet);
  } else {
    Buffer.call(this, buffer);
  }
  if (this.length != binding.sizeof_ogg_packet) {
    throw new Error('"buffer.length" = ' + this.length + ', expected ' + binding.sizeof_ogg_packet);
  }
}
inherits(ogg_packet, Buffer);
```

But, when trying to access *this.length*, I get that error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Method Uint8Array.length called on incompatible receiver [object Object]
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using (not the module's code) that produces the error?

Comment: @mscdex I forgot the code printing the buffer, I just added it to my question. Without that console.log, the tests are failing silently.